# Built in Wireless file management?

Tags: wi-fi, windows, file-transfer, file-management

I connected my Nexus 7 tablet (stock Android 5.1.1) to my Windows 10 computer via USB a few days ago, and saw a notification on my tablet saying something like: *"Still using USB file transfer? Try out Wireless file management"*. I was not running any apps at the time, I had just turned on my tablet. I clicked on it and it directed me to a page in the settings, but I immediately switched applications (i.e. tabbed out) as I was in the middle of something else and decided I would check out this built-in wireless file transfer later, which I assumed must have been included in the latest update I installed.

Unfortunately I forgot to go back and have a look at it. I've tried to search for it again in the settings but cannot find it. Google searches do not help, as they are cluttered with links to third party applications for wireless file transfers. I've also tried connecting the tablet to my computer via USB again, but the notification doesn't show up.

Does anybody know how to enable this **built in wireless file management** that seems to have been included in a newer update? (I know there are many third party apps that can do this, but I am not interested in them)

Also, I assume "wireless file management" means that I can see and access my tablet as a media device (or whatever) when it is connected to my local network through wifi; allowing me to then transfer files to it.

Thanks!

PS: Additional data: Stock android 5.1.1. The build version is LMY47V and the kernel version is 3.1.10-gf5d7b8b. I haven't installed any special drivers, so it must have been the default Nexus 7 Windows USB driver. Couldn't find any relevant setting in developer options.

Comment: Yupp, now everything should be there. Not familiar with Windows, so I cannot help further unfortunately – but with the facts all there, it should be easy for those who are. If you don't get your question answered, and are open to 3rd party solutions, consider asking for them at [SoftwareRecs](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) (link goes to the quality-guidelines on their Meta site), there are several available. // Meanwhile: shall we cleanup our comments here, as you've integrated their details with your post?

Comment: No worries. I hope someone has seen this notification too and will be able to let me know where it comes from. And sure, I'll remove my comments. Thanks for your help